# How can I simulate key events with selenium in a CodeMirror Editor

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, codemirror

There are plenty of examples around that show how to use the following to enter text using selenium

```
driver.execute_script('cm.setValue("text")');
```

This works, but isn't very "selenium" of us. We want to simulate actual keyboard key presses like the send_keys function in selenium. We created a **enterFormData** that gets an element and types to it using driver.send_keys()*(e.g. a textarea with an ID we can easily simulate typing)*. How can we simulate actual key presses into the CodeMirror editor? We also want to be able to test HotKeys *(e.g. Ctrl-Shift-M)* and then take a **driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()**

Comment: Doesn't the way you'd do it for a normal textarea work, if you first ensure that CodeMirror is focused? It is backed by a hidden textarea which will receive the key events.

Answer (score 5):

For selenium to detect the keyboard events, you'll first have to bring codemirror into focus.

You can do something like this:

```
/* getting codemirror element */
WebElement codeMirror = driver.findElement(By.className("CodeMirror"));

/* getting the first line of code inside codemirror and clicking it to bring it in focus */
WebElement codeLine = codeMirror.findElements(By.className("CodeMirror-line")).get(0);
codeLine.click();

/* sending keystokes to textarea once codemirror is in focus */
WebElement txtbx = codeMirror.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea"));
txtbx.sendKeys("Hello World");
```

Comment: It works but typo in codeMirror.findElements(By.className("CodeMirror-line")).get(0); it should be CodeMirror-lines

Answer (score 1):

The codemirror instance should have a hidden textarea in it which captures the keyboard events...

I did something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.css('.CodeMirror textarea'))
    .sendKeys('text', 
        webdriver.Key.chord(webdriver.Key.CONTROL, webdriver.Key.SHIFT, "m"));
```

This bit: `webdriver.Key.chord(webdriver.Key.CONTROL, webdriver.Key.SHIFT, "m")` simulates the (Ctrl+Shift+M)

Comment: Unfortunately the textarea is hidden and selenium shows a not visible exception. I've had to do it via setValue.

Comment: That is interesting because this works in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I myself have found this answer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969245/6077069. You should use driver's action chains instead of element send_keys. This is working in my case.