# How do I edit CodeMirror with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, codemirror

I keep getting the error message below every time I try to insert text into CodeMirror on my webpage. Does anyone know how to successfully edit codemirror with selenium?

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
```

This is my Selenium-Python code

```
def click_component_script_editor(self):
   driver = self.driver
   line18Edit = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html//div[@class='CodeMirror-line']//div[18]/pre[1]")      
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].CodeMirror.setValue(arguments[1]);",
                   line18Edit,
                   "foo.bar")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the answer to this one, I had to use actionChains instead of just regular old send_keys.

```
codeMirror = self.driver.find_element(".CodeMirror")
action_chains.click(codeMirror).perform()
action_chains.send_keys("Hello World").perform()
```

Comment: how about send_keys to partical line of code in codeMirror?

Comment: That causes an "unable to focus element error" every single time.

Comment: well, it turn out i use wait.until to make sure next line of codemirror element is visibility  and repeat to click element and send_keys. ui.WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30).(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(By.css, 'CodeMirror'))

Comment: What is `action_chains` here? `from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains` leads to the error `AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains' has no attribute 'click'`

Comment: @Dan The problem is that you're trying to use `driver.find_element[s]` instead of `driver.find_element`. So one s makes difference. If you want to find single element, you should try like this: Use this way: `driver.find_element_by_link_text(".CodeMirror")` or you want to find whole list, Use like this: `for x in self.driver.find_elements_by_link_text(".CodeMirror"):`\n

`link =webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(x).click(x).perform()`