# Python Selenium Error: "Element not Interactable". Solutions from other posts haven't worked

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, exception, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to utilize selenium python to input text into a text box.

I haven't been able to get this to work yet, because of the "element not interactable" error.
Here's the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/pythoncode/sporg12t.py", 
line 65, in <module> element.send_keys(response) 
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", 
line 231, in send_keys self._execute( 
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", 
line 403, in _execute return self._parent.execute(command, params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", 
line 440, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response) 
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", 
line 245, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

The site with the textbox I'm attempting to input text into is [here](https://www.codestepbystep.com/problem/view/python/algorithms/baggage_colors). You may have to create an account to interact with the text box. Yes, when the code tries to input into the text box, it's signed in.

Here's the relevant section of the program:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'textarea#solution')
element.send_keys(response)
```

where "response" is the text I'd like to input. The full program does the following:

- Sets up selenium stuff (chromeDriver, ect.)
- Gets [website](https://www.codestepbystep.com/problem/view/python/algorithms/baggage_colors)
- Signs in
- Finds [specific page](https://www.codestepbystep.com/problem/view/python/algorithms/baggage_colors)
- Gets [specific page](https://www.codestepbystep.com/problem/view/python/algorithms/baggage_colors)
- Selects instructions paragraph on site
- Reads instructions
- Generates response
- Selects text box
- Inputs response into text box [Error occurs here]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can't run it but `textarea` may different problems which makes it `not interactable`. (1)  can be disabled and - so user can't write text,, (2) can be below bottom line of window - so user can't see it, (2) can be hidden behind other object (like popup window) - so user can write text. If you run code without `--headless` then you should see page in browser - and you should see if `textarea` has some problem.

Comment: Thanks! I did try a few different methods, including direct XPATH and finding it based on keywords, but they've all resulted in the same error. I'm not currently using headless mode, either.

Comment: if you don't use `headless` then you should see page in browser - and you can check if this `textarea` can be used manually. Maybe it is disabled, or it is not visible at this moment. Eventually you can use `input()` to keep opened browser - `input()` will waits for `ENTER` before it ends running code and closing browser.

Comment: I registered on page and I checked this `textarea`. It uses CodeMirror to highlight code - so place for code is not real `textarea` but some other tags. Real `textarea` is hidden - so it is `not interactable`. It may need to use `execute_script` with some JavaScript code to put text in this hidden `textarea`

Comment: [How do I edit CodeMirror with Selenium in Python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956036/how-do-i-edit-codemirror-with-selenium-in-python/48969245#48969245)

Comment: [javascript - How can I simulate key events with selenium in a CodeMirror Editor - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874686/how-can-i-simulate-key-events-with-selenium-in-a-codemirror-editor)

Comment: Sweet, that worked! Thanks - but now I'm getting a new error when the program attempts to click the "Submit" button:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
The button is on-screen and the XPATH is correct (I also tried it with CLASS_NAME and NAME), what's the issue here? Thanks again!

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page. And you should show your code and your `XPATH` - maybe it is not correct.

Comment: BTW: you may always try to select by text `Submit`.